# Count number of times specific text is in an array

Tags: excel, search, countif

I have a list of annoyingly non-standard data, the titles of trouble tickets, that I need to find a way to standardize into categories and then count the number of cells that fall into one of the categories. I have been attempting to use the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G:G,A2)))>0
```

Where G is my list of categories and A2 is the first cell in my list of ticket titles. The issue is this formula just returns TRUE or FALSE, which is not helpful in my case. Does anyone have any suggestions? Here is an example of the data I am dealing with:

```
web browser pointing to wrong web page
excel will not save
outlook popups on startup
logon issue
etc
```

It would be useful if instead of returning TRUE, the formula returned whichever category it found, i.e. if it found browser in the category array, for the first example it would return browser, rather than TRUE.

Comment: What are you trying to count in your example data? You could use a fuzzy countif so for example, to find the number of times `save` is mentioned you could use `=COUNTIF(G:G, "*save*")` or if your search value is in `A2` `=COUNTIF(G:G, "*" & A2 & "*")`

Comment: Also the reason your formula returns `True` is due to the `>0` at the end. Remove this and it should give you the count

Comment: Do you want to count the number of cells in each category, or count the number of categories for each ticket?

Comment: I want to count the number of cells for each category. So if my categories are `outlook, browser, profile` I would have a value for each category, such as `outlook 45 browser 90 profile 20` etc

Comment: @Tom so that gives me a 1 or a 0, but doesn't tell me which category the cell belongs to.

Comment: OK, I posted an answer but you seem to have changed the requirement!? If you want to count the number of cells in column A that contain "Browser" (in G2) then that would just be Tom's suggestion with the Gs and As reversed, i.e. `=COUNTIF(A:A, "*" & G2 & "*")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this formula

`=INDEX(G$2:G$100,MATCH(1,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G$2:G$100,A2))+0,0),0))&""`

If multiple items in `G2:G100` appear in A2 then this will just list the first one (from G2:G100)

Note: if you have "Brow" and "Browser" in the list then it will find both and return the first in the list, so you need to list them with the longest first, ideally, or change to this version so you only match whole words

`=INDEX(G$2:G$100,MATCH(1,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&G$2:G$100&" "," "&A2&" "))+0,0),0))`

The first formula returns a blank if nothing found, the second one returns `#N/A`

`Edit:`

If each category in `G2:G100` has an associated text in adjacent column `H2:H100` then you can change the formula to return the column H value by changing the very first range in the formula, e.g.

`=INDEX(H$2:H$100,MATCH(1,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G$2:G$100,A2))+0,0),0))&""`

Comment: Wow that worked beautifully. Would it be possible to also say if it finds a word in the category to assign another value rather than copying the same category? For example, if the title contains the word excel, I would want the formula to find the word excel in the list of categories but then return the word application rather than excel. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You can do that by changing the first range - see above - I made an edit

Comment: @barryhoudini You're awesome dude. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reverse your logic in that case, and put a formula next to each category (in H:H) with a `COUNTIF`, so in H1:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, "*"&G1&"*")
```

And so on down the column.